# Bootstrap nav tabs working in fiddle but not when opened with Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[Here is](https://jsfiddle.net/pvnt7d2r/) a working JavaScript fiddle version.

I seem to be using the correct syntax, but I can't get it working. It switches to the correct tab in the address bar, but the correct tab or its data isn't showing.

Here is my JavaScript:

```
$(function () {
    $('#myTab a:last').tab('show')
  })
```

Here is my HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div role="tabpanel">
  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#settings" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">Homer</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">Profile</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="messages">View Messages</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="settings">Settings Stuff</div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try loading jquery before bootstrap.

Comment: You fixed it!!! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to keep the ; after your script

```
$(function () {
    $('#myTab a:last').tab('show')
}); <<--THIS ONE
```

Also, move your `jquery.js` and `bootstrap.js` to the `<head>` tag and make sure that jQuery is on top followed by bootstrap and finally this script:

```
$(function () {
    $('#myTab a:last').tab('show')
});
```

Comment: From my experience the semicolon is not necessary, but I tried it and that wasn't the issue :|

Comment: Oh shucks.... Well, did you try moving the js files to the top and in sequence as I mentioned?? It could be because bootstrap js is called before jQuery and after the #myTab function script

Answer (score 0):

Try loading jquery before bootstrap.